# How to compute gcd in real quadratic ring using the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This may be correct or incorrect:

$$\gcd(2, 1 + \sqrt{7}) = 3 + \sqrt{7}.$$

I got this by looking at prime factorizations:

$$(3 - \sqrt{7})(3 + \sqrt{7}) = 2$$

$$(-3 - \sqrt{7})(2 - \sqrt{7}) = 1 + \sqrt{7}$$

It's my understanding that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ is a Euclidean domain, and that the default Euclidean function for this kind of domain is the absolute value of the norm. Then for the first step, I need to solve $1 + \sqrt{7} = 2q + r$ so that $-4 < N(r) < 4$. It seems obvious to me that $r \neq 0$ nor $1$. This leaves a very narrow range, I feel like I'm trying to find a vein on a junkie's arm. I also wondered if maybe I needed to be looking for $2 = q(1 + \sqrt{7}) + r$. I admit I'm getting confused here.

Comment: In this case you know the gcd already, so there's a clue for how to apply the algorithm: for $1+\sqrt{7}=2q+r$, in fact you can find $q$ so that $r=3+\sqrt{7}$. This isn't very satisfying though, because it doesn't tell you how to apply the Euclidean algorithm for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ in general.

Comment: Indeed, @Julian, $q = -1$ leads to $2q = -2$ and $r = 3 + \sqrt{7}$, which doesn't answer the question of how to come to that choice of $q$ from $$\frac{1 + \sqrt{7}}{2} \approx 1.8228756555.$$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ a E.D ? it is not a unique factorization domain since $6= 2(3) = (\sqrt{7}-1)(\sqrt{7} +1) $. so it is not an Euclidean Domain

Comment: @Ameryr The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ is Euclidean. In the example $2(3)=(\sqrt{7}-1)(\sqrt{7}+1)$, none of the four elements $2$, $3$, $\sqrt{7}-1$, or $\sqrt{7}+1$ is prime. The prime factorization is $6=(3+\sqrt{7})(3-\sqrt{7})(2-\sqrt{7})(-2-\sqrt{7})$.

Answer (score 2):

Divide $1 + \sqrt{7}$ by $2$ (put the element with the larger norm in the numerator); you get
$$ \frac{1 + \sqrt{7}}{2}  = \frac12 + \frac12\sqrt{7} .$$ 
Now try  the possible "nearest integers $q = a + b\sqrt{7}$, in the 
present case $a, b \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$. Any constructive proof that the ring of integers ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ is norm-Euclidean will tell you more exactly
where to look for suitable values of $q$. It is usually a good idea to pick
$b$ first and then choose $a$ in such a way that it minimizes the norm.

In the present case, $q = -1$ ($b = 0$, $a = -1$) gives
$$ 1 + \sqrt{7} = (-1) \cdot 2 + 3 + \sqrt{7} $$
and here the remainder has  a smaller norm than $4 = N(2)$.